# how to solve this firebase is not defined error?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to firebase/javascript/html coding, so I really don't know what I'm doing.
But I was following a tutorial on how to make firebase work with a WebGL Unity build and got stuck here:

html code
`

```
<script type="module">
          // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
          import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
          import { getDatabase } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-database.js";
          // Your web app's Firebase configuration
          // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
          const firebaseConfig = {
              apiKey: "apikey",
              authDomain: "authDomain.firebaseapp.com",
              databaseURL: "databaseURL.firebasedatabase.app",
              projectId: "projectId",
              storageBucket: "storageBucket.appspot.com",
              messagingSenderId: "messagingSenderId",
              appId: "appId",
              measurementId: "G-measurementId"
          };
          // Initialize Firebase
          const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
          const db = getDatabase(app);
      </script>
```

`jslib script:`

```
PostJSON: function(path, value, objectName, callback, fallback) {
        var parsedPath = Pointer_stringify(path);
        var parsedValue = Pointer_stringify(value);
        var parsedObjectName = Pointer_stringify(objectName);
        var parsedCallback = Pointer_stringify(callback);
        var parsedFallback = Pointer_stringify(fallback);

        try {

            firebase.database().ref(parsedPath).set(JSON.parse(parsedValue)).then(function(unused) {
                unityInstance.Module.SendMessage(parsedObjectName, parsedCallback, "Success: " + parsedValue + " was posted to " + parsedPath);
            });

        } catch (error) {
            unityInstance.Module.SendMessage(parsedObjectName, parsedFallback, JSON.stringify(error, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error)));
        }
    }
```

`

Every time I try to post a value it says: firebase is not defined.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the namespaced `firebase.database()` syntax of Firebase SDK versions 8 and before with the modular `initializeApp` syntax of Firebase SDK versions 9 and later, which doesn't work.

Since you're initializing the modular SDK, your database access code should use the new modular syntax too:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, set } from "firebase/database";

const db = getDatabase();
set(ref(db, parsedPath), JSON.parse(parsedValue)).then(function(unused) {
    unityInstance.Module.SendMessage(parsedObjectName, parsedCallback, "Success: " + parsedValue + " was posted to " + parsedPath);
});
```

To learn how to upgrade the code, have a look at the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) and keep the Firebase documentation handy as all code samples in there have variants for both syntaxes such as in this page on [reading and writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write).